# error when creating controller scaffolding, Unable to retrieve metadata for

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4, scaffolding

So I'm working my way through this tutorial on [Creating an Entity Framework Data Model for an ASP.NET MVC Application](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application), in the hopes of being able to use the entity frame work to access linked tables. The only deviation I have from this tutorial is I set the providername to `System.Data.EntityClient`, since I'm connecting to a sql2008 server. I run into trouble as soon as I try to add a controller and setting it to scaffold around the Student model class. Here is the exact error,

> Unable to retrieve metadata for 'entities_practice.Models.Student'

Now if instead of using the model I use the Student Entity, and object from my edmx file it builds the controller and views correctly. What am I missing?

Comment: this seems to have something to do with me using a custom dbcontext, vs using the one generated by the entity framework. Maybe that helps?